# Z-index div overlapping fullscreen vimeo wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, z-index

I've been having trouble with my wordpress site's header z-index going on top of vimeo video's when going fullscreen with the video.

link: http://www.dylanhalpern.com/six-points-super-6/

I've tried wrapping the i-frame in div with absolute positioning and a high z-index, and also wrapping that in a div with relative positioning.

css looked like

```
.videowrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: silver;
}
.video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

so html looked like:

```
<div class="videowrap">
 <div class="video">
  <iframe></iframe>
 </div> 
</div>
```

No luck yet, any help appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't see any reason your header needs to have a `z-index` of 100. If you don't declare a z-index for your header, it will be stacked automatically allowing the video to stack higher.

Answer (score 0):

i have tested this code on your [link](http://www.dylanhalpern.com/six-points-super-6/) and  it worked.

```
.site-header{
   z-index: -100;
}
```

Comment: Hi Murtza,
I tried this, but it seems to disable to navigation from being clickable

Comment: @dylan Than you can remove the `z-index` property.

Answer (score 0):

Child elements are positioned within their parent. So you need to somehow change the relative `z-index` of the parents (the parents of your header and video).

In other words, your problem isn't that CSS isn't giving them the proper z-index, but that your `videowrap` div has a lower z-index than the parent of your header (which is probably `body` so you're out of luck there).

If your header is under `body` directly, try wrapping it in a div, then set the z-index of your `videowrap` div to be higher than the header container div (or whatever element your wrap it in).

Comment: After a closer look I found that <div id="content" class"site-content"> was set to 100% width in the css, but was not under the same container aside from <div id="page">. Without the z-index on the header to the left, the nav became unclickable.

To solve this, I set content to 80% width, floated right (with margins set to compensate for the change) and the header 20% width on the left with an undeclared z-index. 

Do you think this is an OK work around?